# EGit does not show any icon on source after untracking a resource

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I use EGit in Eclipse and it is good at first. Today I just select *Untrack* on 
a JavaScript resource as shon below,

[image: Untrack miss]

Now even if I modify the source in `WebContent` and the file to the repository index, no icon appears on filename, How can I use it normally again?

[image: No icon even after add index]

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the *Git Decorator* is active. Go to *Window* > *Preferences* > *General* > *Appearance* > *Label Decorations* and make sure that the *Git Decorator* is checked.

Comment: It's already checked! as you can see not all no icons, only two files...